# PHP get custom tags from a single column and separate them

Tags: php

thanks upfront for reading my question.
So what i have in hands is a textarea that submits to a single column in a table.

Let's say i send this values in only 1 row:

```
<first_name>Sophia</first_name><last_name>Aba</last_name>
<first_name>Ana</first_name><last_name>Bush</last_name>
```

After submiting it goes to the column called Contributors.

Now i want to get from database that value and separate them like this :

```
<?php

$get = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id= '1' ");
$fetch = $get->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$contributors = $fetch['contributors'];
```

But now how can i separate that entry making the php get the name inside  tags and detect how much there is so i can get thoose into separate variables like :

```
<?php 

$count = "HERE COUNT FOR HOW MUCH FIRST_NAME THERE IS "
for($i = 0; i >= $count; $i++){
  $array = ("a","b","c");
  $first_name_$array[$i] = "HERE THE VARIABLE THAT GETS THE FIRST_NAME TAG OF THE FIRST";  // I know this is  incorrect way of incrementing a variable name that's why im also asking for help  
}
```

Comment: So, if I forget your explanation of the form and the database, can I assume that the format you show is a given? One name per line, first name in `first_name` tag and last name in `last_name` tag? In that order, and always present?

Comment: Yes ,  the textarea is supposed to take several authors, but i created a custom tag which fast first_name and last_name to be easy to identify them and count them.

Answer (score 0):

**Do it differently**

First and foremost, I would suggest storing the data differently in the first place. Saving XML and then extracting data from it again after reading it out of a database is just a very complicated way to go (as you can see per your question as to how to do it). See also into [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) for that.

**If you absolutely have to do it this way**

I would recommend using PHPs SimpleXML for that, like so:

```
<?php

$contributors =
"<contributors>
    <contributor>
        <first_name>Sophia</first_name>
        <last_name>Aba</last_name>
    </contributor>
    <contributor>
        <first_name>Ana</first_name>
        <last_name>Bush</last_name>
    </contributor>
</contributors>";

$xmlContributors = new SimpleXMLElement($contributors);

foreach ($xmlContributors->children() as $contributor) {
    echo 'This is one contributor: ' . $contributor->first_name . ' ' . $contributor->last_name . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note however, that you'd have to change your XML structure for that to have some sensible XML buildup at all (as shown above).

Comment: But how could i in php from that textfield lets say if i send without xml. The text in the textarea would be forexample "Name Last; Name Last; Name Last;" the textarea input would go to 1 column but how could i know much names there was inside that textarea and then atribute a variable to each of them

Comment: @Gongas You could use a combination of [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and/or possibly [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) for that.